# function called in wrong button click event using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having 2 div elements say div1, div2and 2 buttons 'add image' and 'discard image'(initially hidden).

When I click add image button, it adds 2 images to all div.
when image inside any div get clicked 'discard image' button get visible,so when i clicked this discard some functionality.

I have written click event on image in both div separately as well discard btn click function as below.

```
   if($.trim($("#div1").html())=='')
   {
      $("#div1").append("<img id='grpA0' width='60px' height='60px' src="1.png">");
      $("#div1").append("<img id='grpA0' width='60px' height='60px' src="2.png">");

      $("#grpA0").click(function() 
      {
        $("#discard_image").show();////shows hidden discard btn
      });
      $("#discard_image").click(function()
     {
        alert("in div1 discard");
        /// some code                                   
    });
}

if($.trim($("#div2").html())=='')
{
    $("#div2").append("<img id='grpB0' width='60px' height='60px' src="3.png">");
    $("#div2").append("<img id='grpB0' width='60px' height='60px' src="4.png">");

    $("#grpB0").click(function() 
    {
        $("#discard_image").show(); ////shows hidden discard btn
    });
    $("#discard_image").click(function()
     {
         alert("in div2 discard");
        /// some code                                   
    });
}
```

my question is when i clicked image from div1 ,discard btn shown but on discard button click both alerts are shown. i tried to send e as event in discard click and used     e.preventDefault(); but its not working

Comment: Try to use a different id for the two `discard_image` buttons.

Answer (score 0):

id attribute of html should be unique in your html pages.

You created 2 div with same id. 1st in div1 2nd in div2.

So Basically you are binding two elentet your discard element. This is why you are getting both alert.

```
$("#discard_card").click(function()
  {
    alert("in div1 discard");
    /// some code                                   
});
$("#discard_card").click(function()
  {
     alert("in div2 discard");
    /// some code                                   
});
```

To solve this problem you need to give unique id for both div. You can try discard_1, discard_card_1 and discard_2, discard_card_2

```
if($.trim($("#div1").html())=='')
   {
      $("#div1").append("<img id='grpA0' width='60px' height='60px' src="1.png">");
      $("#div1").append("<img id='grpA0' width='60px' height='60px' src="2.png">");

      $("#grpA0").click(function() 
      {
        $("#discard_1").show();
      });
      $("#discard_card_1").click(function()
     {
        alert("in div1 discard");
        /// some code                                   
    });
}

if($.trim($("#div2").html())=='')
{
    $("#div2").append("<img id='grpB0' width='60px' height='60px' src="3.png">");
    $("#div2").append("<img id='grpB0' width='60px' height='60px' src="4.png">");

    $("#grpB0").click(function() 
    {
        $("#discard_2").show();
    });
    $("#discard_card_2").click(function()
     {
         alert("in div2 discard");
        /// some code                                   
    });
}
```

Please also update the id value in html as well.

Comment: thanks for answer , but i wrote some wrong code , please check i have updated my question. :-(

Comment: If I am not wrong you have id discard_image for two div ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the same discard button for both items, it's a good idea to unbind listeners before binding new ones.

```
$("#discard_card").unbind();
```

Furthermore, do this when required (i.e. on show):

```
$("#grpB0").click(function() {
  $("#discard").show();

  $("#discard_card")
  .unbind()
  .on('click', function() {
    alert("in div2 discard");
    /// some code                                   
  });
});
```

Full corrected code (including " changed to ' inside quotes):

```
if ($.trim($("#div1").html()) == '') {
  $("#div1").append("<img id='grpA0' width='60px' height='60px' src='1.png'>");
  $("#div1").append("<img id='grpA0' width='60px' height='60px' src='2.png'>");

  $("#grpA0").click(function() {
    $("#discard_image").show(); ////shows hidden discard btn
    $("#discard_card").unbind()
      .on('click', function() {
        alert("in div1 discard");
        /// some code                                   
      });
  });

}

if ($.trim($("#div2").html()) == '') {
  $("#div2").append("<img id='grpB0' width='60px' height='60px' src='3.png'>");
  $("#div2").append("<img id='grpB0' width='60px' height='60px' src='4.png'>");

  $("#grpB0").click(function() {
    $("#discard_image").show(); ////shows hidden discard btn
    $("#discard_card").unbind()
      .on('click', function() {
        alert("in div2 discard");
        /// some code                                   
      });
  });

}
```

Here is a working jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/maxbilbow/cyazd4mn/2/

Comment: hi i tried it but still its going in both functions :-(

Comment: Have you copied the above code exactly and cleared your browser cache?

Comment: @Nil I have created a fiddle here that works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/maxbilbow/cyazd4mn/2/

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of issues, one big one being that `id` attribute should be unique. Use `class` to designate multiple tags.

When you need to attach events specific to certain elements in your DOM, using a `data-[something]` attribute is often a good idea that allows you to use just a single event handler instead of attaching separate handlers for each item.

I'm guessing at your html structure, but this snippet is an example of what I mean by using `data` attributes:

```js
if($.trim($("#div1").html())=='')
   {
      $("#div1").append("<img class='group' id='one' width='60px' height='60px' src='1.png'>");
      $("#div1").append("<img class='group' id='two' width='60px' height='60px' src='2.png'>");
}

if($.trim($("#div2").html())=='')
{
    $("#div2").append("<img class='group' id='three' width='60px' height='60px' src='3.png'>");
    $("#div2").append("<img class='group' id='four' width='60px' height='60px' src='4.png'>");
}

$('.group').click(function(event) {
  var divNum = $(event.target).closest('div').data('num');
  $(".discard[data-num='" + divNum + "']").show();
});

$('.discard_card').click(function(event) {
  var divNum = $(event.target).closest('div').data('num');
  alert('Clicked discard for div' + divNum);
});
```

```css
#one { background-color: yellow; }
#two { background-color: pink; }
#three { background-color: grey; }
#four { background-color: cyan; }

.discard { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
 <div id="div1" data-num="1"></div>
 <div class="discard" data-num="1">
     <button class="discard_card">Discard</button>
 </div>
 
 <div id="div2" data-num="2"></div>
 <div class="discard" data-num="2">
     <button class="discard_card">Discard</button>
 </div>
```